# Getting Scanner as WIACAMERA in Morena 7

Tags: java, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

My jdev version is 11.1.2.4. I am using Morena 7 for scanning.My Scanner is HP DeskJet 2050.I am getting my scanner as WIACAMERA instead of scanner.

Manager manager=Manager.getInstance();
        List devices = manager.listDevices();

```
    Device device=devices.get(0);
      if (device instanceof Scanner)  { } //getting my scanner as WIACAMERA
```

Any Idea ?

Answer (score 0):

I solved a similar issue by referring to Morena docs

```
Configuration.addDeviceType(".*fficejet.*", true);  
manager = Manager.getInstance();
```

Taken from the following site
[http://www.gnome.eu/Morena/doc/tutorial7.html]

For my Canon scanner I added the following

```
Configuration.addDeviceType(".*CANON.*", true);
```